Accessing HTML Content within an Iframe in a Closed Shadow Root Using Selenium
I am currently operating a website that incorporates a web component with a native closed shadow root. This web component includes an iframe within its structure. My objective is to utilize Selenium to access the HTML content within the iframe, which would allow me to verify that the right content is being presented. Regrettably, Selenium's getShadowRoot function is not performing as expected with the native shadow due to its closed nature. Furthermore, when an attempt is made to access the iframe using switchTo().frame(index), the operation is unsuccessful because of the closed shadow.
Is there any possible solution to this issue?
HTML
<script type="module" async="async" src="https://www.example.org/script.js"></script>
<sample-application title="Sample App"></sample-application>

JavaScript
class SampleApplication extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const iframe = window.document.createElement('iframe');
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
        iframe.name = 'sample-iframe';

        const title = this.getAttribute("title");
        if (title) {
            iframe.title = title;
        }
        iframe.src = "https://www.example.org/iframe.html";
        shadow.appendChild(iframe);
    }
}
window.customElements.define('sample-application', SampleApplication);

I would appreciate any assistance if finding a way with Selenium to access the content in the iframe.

No, closed means closed. You may have to rethink your test; when you buy a new car, do you test the valves in the engine or just that it runs smooth? The component author tests the components components. And if you do test the valves, it comes at a cost.. you have to take the engine apart. That's what you can do with closed components too. Extract its JavaScript and create a new Component to test the component valves

Recreating (reverse engineering) a Component based on another componnts source, comes at about 2 to 3 times the original cost. Because you now have to test everything... maybe the component relied on being closed

Since I own the component and site in the iframe, I can create a version without the closed shadow.  I just wanted to avoid making a less secure version that is different from what will used by my users.  In my specific case, I am trying to access the Performance metrics from the inner iframe and correlate them with similar metrics from the outer page.

Sounds interesting

I looked into prying open a closed Web Component. Its a PITA.
Since you own the Web Component.
I think your best approach is creating an open Web Component,
and "disable" this.shadowRoot with a getter, displaying the error.stack
That .shadowRoot is basically the only difference between "open" and "closed"


<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(
      createElement = (t,p={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(t),p)    
    ) {
      super()
        .attachShadow({ mode:"open" })
        .append(
          createElement("style", {
            textContent: `:host{display:block} slot{ color: green }` 
          }),
          "Hello ",
          createElement("slot", { textContent: "cool" }),
          " Web Components"
        );
    }
    get shadowRoot() {
      const error = new Error(`can't access shadowRoot`);
      console.error(error.stack);
      return null;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log("shadowRoot", this.shadowRoot);
    }
  });
</script>

<my-component>great</my-component>
<my-component>awesome [pun intended]</my-component>



